# How can we fix subfigure in multicols enviroment

Tags: subfloats, multicol

I am using `{multicols*}{2}` and want to show nonfloating subfigures and have tried following method, but no success, rather it does not show anything. Could you please guide me about the solution.

```
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfigure[$\text{Participant Overlap}(PO)=60\%$]{\includegraphics[width=3.5in]{TSp0802060fresh3.eps} \label{fig:TSa}}%
\subfigure[$\text{Participant Overlap}(PO)=100\%$]{\includegraphics[width=3.5in]{TSp08020100fresh3.eps} \label{fig:TSc}}\\
\subfigure[$\text{Participant Overlap}(PO)=60\%$]{\includegraphics[width=3.5in]{TLp0802060fresh3.eps} \label{fig:TLa}}%
\subfigure[$\text{Participant Overlap}(PO)=100\%$]{\includegraphics[width=3.5in]{TLp08020100fresh3.eps} \label{fig:TLc}}%
\caption{Sample values of TS and TL selected from Table \ref{tab:TS},\ref{tab:TL} for depiction.}
\label{fig:TSTL}
\end{figure}
\end{multicols*}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: I think you need to use the `figure*` environment when using multiple columns.

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  While solving problems is fun, setting them up is not. Then those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my view point the problmes is: the image overlap whit the limit of the document and place it where latex think its the best (this case, "does not fit don't put it") one of the solutions i did was to make latex obey the placement u be stated, to do it so u can use the package \float after that just add [H] after \begin{figure} (\begin{figure}[H]) and it will show.

here's my sample code:

```
\RequirePackage{snapshot}
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{adjustwidth}{-1in}{-1in}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{figure}[H]

\centering
\subfigure[$\text{Participant Overlap}(PO)=60\%$]{\includegraphics[width=3.5in]{figs/cat.jpg} \label{fig:TSa}}%
\subfigure[$\text{Participant Overlap}(PO)=100\%$]{\includegraphics[width=3.5in]{figs/cat.jpg} \label{fig:TSc}}\\
\subfigure[$\text{Participant Overlap}(PO)=60\%$]{\includegraphics[width=3.5in]{figs/cat.jpg} \label{fig:TLa}}%
\subfigure[$\text{Participant Overlap}(PO)=100\%$]{\includegraphics[width=3.5in]{figs/cat.jpg} \label{fig:TLc}}%
\caption{Sample values of TS and TL selected from Table \ref{tab:TS},\ref{tab:TL} for depiction.}
\label{fig:TSTL}

\end{figure}
\end{multicols}
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

I added \adjustwidth so it can be centered and fit on the page width.

(English is not my native idiom, sorry for the bad grammar)

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked and now I can see the Figure, but results in another problem, I have got two-column text in the document above and below these Figures, and the text of second (right hand side) column appear over two of these Figures. How can we force text not to appear like this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can just make the figures appear on a single page and the text on the next page, just add \newpage before and next of the figure page. Its just a temporal solution.